# Spotlight change keywords in Yosemite

Tags: spotlight, macos

Spotlight seems to always suggest the wrong thing and doesn't learn when I don't choose the Top Hit.

Is it possible to change the priorities of Spotlight? The internet suggests that there has been a way to edit keywords (or Spotlight comments) under "right click/Get Info". But there is no such thing here in Yosemite anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Spotlight -> Search Results allows you to change the order of results by reordering categories.  As far as specific items within a category, this answer suggests that Spotlight is supposed to learn the Top Hit from what you choose over time: [Changing OS X Spotlight priorities for specific applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29485/changing-os-x-spotlight-priorities-for-specific-applications?rq=1).

[image]

Comment: If there's some better way I'd love to know.  Most people who address this sort of question say to use a third-party launcher, but Spotlight is getting quite capable and I personally found the launchers I tried to be too complex to get started easily (QuickSilver, which I had very high hopes for, and Alfred, which I also had high hopes for some months after giving up on QuickSilver).

Comment: Just now I saw Spotlight learn a new top hit, so I can verify that it definitely learns in at least some cases. In this case it had previously learned a particular spreadsheet was a top hit, and quickly learned that I now favored a new version of it that had a different name.

Comment: Top Hits are still on the top and are considered more important

Comment: I assume your custom Top Hit didn't replace an apple program like iTunes. For example if I type in "music" iTunes will always show up first, no matter how often I pick the other result.

Comment: Correct, it simply replaced a prior document I usually opened with a new one that I now favor.

Comment: It looks like Apple programs _can_ be replaced as top hits in some instances. I'm trying to launch the App Store, however [typing "App" has Android Studio as a top hit](http://i.imgur.com/jd4frLu.png) for me. Typing "app" (note lowercase) gives App Store as top hit.